# What are the odds of the loot boxes in overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

When you open a loot box, you can get a chance to get items of different rarities.

To be available in china, I heard that they need to have their loot box odds publicly available, [like League of Legends did](https://www.pcgamesn.com/league-of-legends/league-of-legends-hextech-crafting-odds)

So are the ones of Overwatch available, and if so, what are they?

Comment: Wait until it gets officially released like it did for LoL and you'll know.

Comment: Well I might not have seen it pass. Thats why I ask.

Comment: @TimmyJim OP here asks for the actual real numbers that Blizzard is due to publish at some point. The provided answer here and the question/answers for the one you cite only speculate based on players opening boxes and making assumptions from there they are not the actual percentages Blizzard is using those will be published at some point in the future.

Comment: @ИвоНедев The questions are duplicates, the answers don't matter

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Putting the actual title of the question aside, read the last line of the question above "is the data available"

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer and others -- I cannot vote to reopen due to rep - but Blizzard just released the official rates for China if we want to add that in. I have the article. http://www.pcgamer.com/blizzard-reveals-overwatch-loot-box-drop-rates-in-china/

Comment: @n_palum The questions are still duplicates

Comment: Nevermind - @ИвоНедев has :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if they're published by Blizzard, but [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4mbpz9/loot_box_drop_rate_1000_boxes_sample_size/) by ourobouros suggests that the distribution is about

- 59% commons (white)
- 32% rares (blue)
- 7.2% epics (purple)
- 2.4% legendary (yellow)

Note that you get 4 drops per-box, so about every 4th box you'd get an epic (26%) or 11 boxes a legendary (9.4%).

The OP watched ~1000 box openings on YouTube about a year ago (post is dated June 3, 2016), so drop rates may have changed since then, and might especially be different for seasonal/event boxes. Supposedly all the seasonal boxes [have had the same rate](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753106825?page=2#post-26) ([via](https://www.kotaku.com.au/2017/02/despite-outcry-blizzard-says-overwatch-loot-box-drop-rates-havent-changed/)), not sure if they're different *en bloc* from normal though.

Comment: Supposedly Blizzard will be required to post them now, at least if they do business in China because of a new law that went into effect today.

Comment: @Powerlord not sure when specifically (have an article to cite?) but [this Kotaku.au post](https://www.kotaku.com.au/2016/12/china-will-force-games-with-loot-boxes-to-disclose-odds/) mentions that.

Comment: That's not even remotely close. It is some numbers but its not official information. Only a conclusion from rather small sample number. Blizzard will release the official information at some point

Comment: @ИвоНедев small being 1000 boxes or 4000 items? Define "remotely close"? The last digit probably isn't accurate, but assuming it's uniformly random, there's a 99% chance the true legendary drop rate per item is between 1.8% and 3.1%.

Comment: @NickT Given there's 30m players and they've all opened at least one loot box, 1000 boxes are quite the small number. There's been update from blizzard refer to my answer on the other question to see how off the guesstimates were

Answer (score 1):

They haven't released the information yet. I'll update as soon as they become available.

Update:
Blizzard (China) just reviled some numbers, at least for now it is not know if these numbers apply for China only, or for China and any other region.

- Every Loot Box contains one item of **Rare** (blue) or higher quality **100%** of the time.
- For every 5.5 boxes opened (**18.2%**), a **Epic** item (purple) will be inside.
- For every 13.5 boxes opened (**7.4%**), a **Legendary** (gold) item will be inside.

It is believed that these numbers are valid worldwide but this is not yet confirmed. They are confirmed to apply for China. I'll update as soon as more information is available.